# MYSQL Update column with Sequential numeric value IF NULL - Continued Sequence

Tags: mysql, sequence

I am attempting to keep a running sequence number for a table.
I will run the query on schedule each night to update a table and populate the sequential number based on the last number +1 and continued.

My Table: mis_order_charges

```
ID    item_id    SEQ
1       20        1
5       15        2
6       21        3
9       20       NULL
12      21       NULL
```

So I would like to run an update query to populate the NULL with 4 and 5, and of course continue this each run.

I have tried a few things:

```
insert into misc_order_charges (seq)
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row
FROM misc_order_charges moc, (SELECT @row := 0) r where seq is null;
```

**Didn't work**

```
UPDATE misc_order_charges
JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) r
SET seq=@rank:=@rank+1 where misc_order_charges.seq is null;
```

**The above worked but of course reset the counted, so the NULLs got 1 & 2**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Alter your table and add AUTO INCREMENT to the sequence column

Comment: @PradeepRajput That's not what an autoincrement does (or rather that's not what it's guaranteed to do)

Comment: In general, it's considered a bad idea to do this.

Comment: @Strawberry bad idea when altering Identity key. SEQ field might have completely different needs. Whether this field should be calculated on the fly is another topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the max value using MAX() function to use as base for rank variable.

i.e.

```
UPDATE misc_order_charges
JOIN (SELECT @rank := (SELECT MAX(T.SEQ) FROM misc_order_charges as T)) r
SET seq=@rank:=@rank+1 where misc_order_charges.seq is null;
```

This will get the first rank as whatever highest SEQ number is in your table.

Comment: Thank you! Great suggestion, I believe this will work.